# JavaScript - function not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

With the code below I want to the function to run when it called , for now nothing is happening, does the name of the function unacceptable?

```
function zoom(d) {
  if (d == "in")
    $("#animation_border").css("height", ($(window).height() * 100 / 85) + "px");
  else
    $("#animation_border").css("height", (canvas.width * 0.719) + "px");

}

if ($(window).width() >= 619) {
  zoom("out");
} else {
  zoom("in");
}
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to make `zoom` happen when the window is resized?

Comment: the code seems OK , just a "}" at the end. do you execute this on document ready ,window resize ,or some other actions ?

Comment: If you expect something to happen on window resize, then capture window resize event and have your code in there `$(window).resize(function(){/* YOUR CODE HERE */})`

Comment: yes daniel...Vladu i removed that but it also not working, is using it in the document ready a problem?

Comment: Put that `if ($(window).width() >= 619) {
  zoom("out");
} else {
  zoom("in");
}` inside `$(window).resize(function(){/* YOUR CODE HERE */})` and that's gonna work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to call the `zoom()` function when the window is resized. If so, we can use the `$(window).resize()` event to get what you want:

```
function zoom(d) {
  if (d == "in") {
    // Your code here
  } else {
    // Your code here
  };
}

// Automatically called when window is resized
$(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() >= 619) {
    zoom("out");
  } else {
    zoom("in");
  };
})
```

Working JSFidde: https://jsfiddle.net/209m4esk/2/

As a side note, it would be more efficient to compare a boolean in your `zoom()` function rather than a string. We should also allow for invalid parameters given to the function. i.e:

```
function zoom(zoomIn) {
  if (typeof(zoomIn) !== "boolean") {
      console.log("Parameter given is not a boolean.");
  } else if (zoomIn) {
    // Your code here
  } else {
    // Your code here
  };
}
```

So then you'd simply call `zoom(true)` to zoom in, and `zoom(false)` to zoom out.

Answer (score 1):

- first you have `}`
- put your code in `window.resize`

  ```
  (function(){
  function zoom(d) {
    if (d == "in")
      $("#animation_border").css("height", ($(window).height() * 100 / 85) + "px");
    else
      $("#animation_border").css("height", (canvas.width * 0.719) + "px");

  }

  $(window).resize(function(){
      if ($(window).width() >= 619) {
        zoom("out");
      } else {
        zoom("in");
      }
  })})();
  ```